# Examples of great presentations and alternatives to Beamer

Tags: beamer, presentations

I am familiar with beamer and have used it extensively but I was blown off when I saw this:

https://mse.redwoods.edu/darnold/math55/WritingScientificPapers/project_latex.pdf

I would like to know how such a thing can be done, if there are pre-existing packages like beamer, and some neat examples like this. Does anyone know?

Comment: Looks cool, but definitely not a presentation worthy imo. Presentations shouldn't be wall of text, rather a short notes important to the talk you are giving...

Comment: I think the real point of pdfscreen is to be screen optimized, which is handy. I even used it to make a mobile-screen friendly version of a paper.

Comment: link is dead heres new one
http://msemac.redwoods.edu/~darnold/math55/WritingScientificPapers/project_latex.pdf

Comment: YADL (Yet another dead link) see now https://mse.redwoods.edu/darnold/math55/WritingScientificPapers/project_latex.pdf

Comment: Beamer and alternative tools: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15198/are-there-alternatives-to-beamer-for-slides/15199#15199

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The beginning of the preamble. By the way, replace the `.pdf` with `.tex` and you'll get the source

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{xspace,colortbl}
\usepackage[screen,panelright,code,bluelace,paneltoc]{pdfscreen}
\margins{.5in}{.5in}{.5in}{.5in}
\screensize{6in}{8in}
\overlay{aaCWS.jpg}
\emblema{logo_cir.jpg}
\urlid{http://online.redwoods.cc.ca.us/instruct/darnold}
\usepackage{amsmath}
...
```

Answer (score 6):

This document looks as if it has been created using the `pdfscreen` (LaTeX) package.

Comment: that's an amazing package.