# Showcase of beautiful presentations in Beamer

Tags: beamer, typography, presentations, big-list, examples

I would like to know to what extent Beamer can produce professional presentations. The following following are the requirements :

1. The contribution must be a TeX solution to this question.
2. Usage of **user-defined packages** and **fonts** is allowed.
3. For drawing the diagrams (Smart Arts or 3D diagrams) `TikZ`, `pstricks` or `asymptote` can be used.

   The submission should include a short description and a screenshot of the output.

   There aren't sample layouts. The limit is your own imagination.

### Note 1:

1. On 25th May 2014, I have decided to close my question and accept the showcases
2. I have decided to provide a bounty of 200 for the best solution

### Note 2:

**BTW, I just wanted to know the fantastic features of beamer. So introduced a Showcase question similar to [Showcase of beautiful typography done in TeX & friends](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends?rq=1) and [Showcase TeX Typography for TUG's Calendar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134638/showcase-tex-typography-for-tugs-calendar?rq=1) and these are not a part of my assignments ;)**

Comment: *Design my slides for me and I'll reward you with fake Internet money*? Thanks, but I think I'll pass.

Comment: _I would like to know to what extent Beamer can produce professional presentations._ Professional, is the key point: are you sure the template provided is professional? Maybe to some extent. BTW: it is nice to forbid _any usage of user-defined packages and fonts_...

Comment: Beamer is a user-defined package, and so is pgf/tikz. Sounds pretty professional already! `;-)`

Comment: @Jubobs please see my edited qyestion

Comment: Possible Related/Duplicate of [Beautiful presentations done with TeX and related systems](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105621/beautiful-presentations-done-with-tex-and-related-systems)

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino I have removed the restriction. Please see the edit

Comment: @subhamsoni: now it makes more sense, at least to me. However, I noticed the question linked by texenthusiast and it seems really a duplicate. Don't you think? Perhaps you can add a bounty to that question to give rise to new answers.

Comment: @subhamsoni I won't vote to reopen the question. First, it's way to similar to the other question. Second, I'm not really fond of these threads, and IMHO only like one or two of these make any sense at all.

Comment: @subhamsoni I agree with tohecz on this one.