# What are the most attractive themes in beamer?

Tags: beamer, themes

I am preparing a presentation in Latex Beamer class. Previously I had used the themes Antibes, Berkeley, Warsaw and Progressbar. I want to try something different now. So, what are the best themes that I can use ?

Comment: What happened to the saying, You can't argue about tastes?

Comment: Ya thats true .. everyone has a different taste. But some people may have same taste too. So I will choose those themes which I find interesting :)

Comment: @Debashish: right, but I think the question is still too broad. Narrowing its scope would be beneficial for the site.

Comment: See also: [Beautiful presentations done with TeX and related systems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/105621/5645)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See http://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/  for an overview. There are other themes in the net which are not on CTAN. By the way: the meaning of *attractive* is different ... ;-)