# What is best Latex template could be used for presentation?

Tags: templates, presentations

I'm looking for good template that I can use to make my MS thesis presentation defense, I think there are many, but if some used to do good presentation for PHD or MS thesis defense, can provide some suggestions form his/her experience.
Waiting for feedback.

Comment: I suggest you use the `beamer` class. I would just use the default styles, or if you want to some simple them such as `Bodilla` or `Antibes`. Keep it _simple._ What counts is the quality of the content, not your dazzling-your-audience skills. See the [link](http://csweb.ucc.ie/~dongen/LAF/Beamer.pdf) on my [LaTeX and Firends](http://csweb.ucc.ie/~dongen/LAF/LAF.html) pages for an introduction to `beamer`.

Comment: Your question as it stands is very likely to be put on hold as "primarily opinion-based". Before or after that happens, you can [edit] your question to improve it: try to ask a more specific question that doesn't depend on the answerer's aesthetic preferences. You can also get some more ideas about what's possible at [Beautiful presentations done with TeX and related systems](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/105621)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely `beamer`, see http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf for detailed documentation or http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Presentations for hands-on manual.

Using it is easy: It defines the `frame` environment where you put the contents of your slide. Use the `\pause` command to make items appear on the slide one by one.