# Presentation recommendation

Tags: beamer, presentations

I am a rusty, irregular LaTeX user and I am would like to create a presentation with LaTeX.

I am hoping to get good screen, html and pdf output.  I dont want anything fancy,  mostly just a simple clean look. What should I be looking at? I had a quick look around and found Beamer, but was wondering if that is my best option or if I should look around for other options.

My main desire is to use a plain text input so that I can use git properly to track changes rather than mucking around with some WYSIWYG package none of which I like anyway..

Comment: Look at the question: [Are there alternatives to Beamer for slides ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15198/are-there-alternatives-to-beamer-for-slides)

Answer (score 4):

I think the default setting of Beamer will suit your need.
LaTeX uses at least one input file as the main. It is a plain text file.
For better management, split the contents into several sectional files, and import them from within the main file.

VCS  softwares (such as GIT or Subversion) only need to keep track the `*.tex` and other imported files (images, source code, etc). You can ignore auxiliary files that are generated by LaTeX compiler.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I wrote my thesis and a lot of other stuff at uni with LaTeX. Used to be active on comp.text.tex a lot. But thats a long time ago ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Just in case you're after a lightweight system for authoring Beamer slides in Markdown, you might take a look at [Breakdown](http://dgh.livejournal.com/14603.html?thread=56843), [wiki2beamer](http://wiki2beamer.sourceforge.net/), some [custom template](http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~sinclair/content/blog/using_markdown_for_beamer_presentations) for [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/), or [MultiMarkdown](http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/use/).

I personally like and use [FoilTeX](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/foiltex) or ConTeXt [slides templates](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Presentation_Styles).

Comment: FoilTeX seems pretty unmaintained. Some of the others look very interesting. Thanks a lot.