# Which alternatives to the beamer class exist?

Tags: beamer, presentations

The title is pretty much self-explanatory. Do you know any LaTeX based beamer alternative? In my university, everyone is using beamer, and every presentation has the same layout, I'm sick of it. I was even wondering to create the individual slides in inkscape and merging them afterwards...

Comment: See the question: [Are there alternatives to Beamer for slides](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15198/are-there-alternatives-to-beamer-for-slides).

Comment: Worth pointing out here that like anything one can overdo the 'effects' in `beamer`. I go for very 'light-weight' slides, much of the form of real printed slides of the past. Such things are not aimed at being 'advertising'/'sales' but just having what _needs_ to be on the board/screen available.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Is everyone using the same beamer theme? You could select a different one, or even design your own (e.g. see the [Beamer guide by K-J Kim](http://faq.ktug.or.kr/wiki/uploads/beamer_guide.pdf) and look at the [docs and examples on CTAN](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/)).

Sites that show examples of common themes include:

http://www.pletscher.org/writings/latex/beamerthemes.php

http://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/    (can take a while to load but gives an easily-absorbed overview)

http://deic.uab.es/~iblanes/beamer_gallery/    (select by theme, color or font)

Many users have made themes they have developed available (check the licensing before using them), e.g. http://juluribk.com/2010/04/18/beamer-themes/

Comment: Absolutely!  There's nothing wrong with beamer that a new theme won't fix.

Answer (score 21):

Yes there are. Here are some choices (with descriptions taken from CTAN), in decreasing order of recommended usage:

- [`powerdot` document class](http://ctan.org/pkg/powerdot)

  > `powerdot` is a presentation class for LaTeX that allows for the quick
  >   and easy development of professional presentations. It comes with many
  >   tools that enhance presentations and aid the presenter. Examples are
  >   automatic overlays, personal notes and a handout mode. To view a
  >   presentation, DVI, PS or PDF output can be used. A powerful template
  >   system is available to easily develop new styles. A LyX layout file is
  >   provided.
- [`prosper` document class](http://ctan.org/pkg/prosper)

  > Prosper is a LaTeX class for writing transparencies. It is written as
  >   an extension of the `seminar` class by Timothy Van Zandt.
  >
  > Prosper offers a friendly environment for creating slides for both
  >   presentations with an overhead projector and a video projector. Slides
  >   prepared for a presentation with a computer and a video projector may
  >   integrate animation effects, incremental display, and so on. Various
  >   visual styles are supported (including some that mimic PowerPoint) and
  >   others are being contributed.
- [`seminar` document class](http://ctan.org/pkg/seminar)

  > A class that produces overhead slides (transparencies), with many
  >   facilities. The class requires availability of the [`fancybox`
  >   package](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancybox).
  >
  > `seminar` is also the basis of other classes, such as `prosper`. In
  >   fact, `seminar` is not nowadays reckoned a good basis for a
  >   presentation — users are advised to use more recent classes such as
  >   `powerdot` or `beamer`, both of which are tuned to 21st-century
  >   presentation styles.

Comment: In reality,  `powerdot` is the only full-featured LaTeX alternative to `beamer`.  It is meant to be a replacement for `prosper`. From the documentation "[...] the start of a new project set up to make a new class to replace the `prosper` plus `HA-prosper` combination. You’re currently reading the result of that project.". And `seminar` is even older, and can't really be recommended.

Comment: @Alan: Thanks for the suggestion. I've updated my answer to reflect a recommended preference of usage.

Comment: You can find some more under ["Presentation Slides"](http://ftp.gui.uva.es/sites/ctan.org/help/Catalogue/bytopic.html#present) topic in The TeX Catalogue.

Comment: One issue I have with Beamer is the slow compilation of listings-heavy slide decks due to the need for `fragile` frames, which write and create external vrb files. Does powerdot take a similar approach with its support for code listings?

Comment: @user4417: I have not used [`powerdot`](//ctan.org/pkg/powerdot) myself so cannot comment on that.

Answer (score 7):

> The [`overlays` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/overlays) allows to write presentations with incremental slides. It does not presuppose any specific document class. Rather, it is a lightweight alternative to full-fledged presentation classes like [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[% ...taken from beamer.cls
  papersize={12.8cm,9.6cm},
  hmargin=1cm,%
  vmargin=1cm,% beamer.cls uses 0cm
  head=0.5cm,% might be changed later
  headsep=0pt,%
  foot=0.5cm% might be changed later
  ]{geometry}
  \usepackage{overlays}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\sffamily

\begin{overlays}{4}
  This\only{2-}{ is}\only{3-}{ an}\only{4}{ overlay.}
\end{overlays}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

There is an interesting [PracTeX Journal article](http://tug.org/pracjourn/2010-2/hofert.html) which describes how to create a presentation with [KOMA Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script).

Comment: This looks useful for me: +1

Answer (score 1):

Search [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/search/?search=slide&search_type=description) for "slide" and you'll find you have several to choose from (prosper, slides, uwmslide, etc)