# Pros and cons of different presentation classes?

Tags: presentations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which package to use for presentations ? Beamer, Prosper, or Other](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16204/which-package-to-use-for-presentations-beamer-prosper-or-other)

The Tex.SE-wiki mentions `beamer`, `powerdot`, `HA-prosper`, `prosper`, `slides` and `seminar` under the [presentations](/questions/tagged/presentations) tag. Please, outline their strengths and weaknesses. Which purposes are they meant for?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16204/which-package-to-use-for-presentations-beamer-prosper-or-other and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27267/which-alternatives-to-the-beamer-class-exist for some information

Comment: `HA-prosper`, `prosper`, `slides`, and `seminar` are really outdated