# An alternative to Beamer

Tags: lyx

Could somebody suggest a software more flexible than Beamer (Lyx) to do a good presentation ? An alternative for presentation ?

Best,

Comment: Please elaborate on your requirements: simply 'more flexible' is not really a spec we can work from.

Comment: There are also two other LaTeX classes called Prosper and Powerdot as an alternative to Beamer. Are they more flexible? It boils down to taste I guess.

Comment: For some general information about alternatives to  `beamer` (not specifically in Lyx) look at this post for instance https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16204/141947

Comment: @schtandard IMHO this is not a duplicate, due to the Lyx mention. Otherwise, I agree, there is a connection

Comment: I still use pdfscreen and texpower, mostly because what works in LaTeX doesn't always work in Beamer.

Comment: @BambOo maybe.. The answer to the question may be "Don't use LyX" in that case. OP should clarify what exactly about `beamer` is bothering them. Otherwise, this will be closed as unclear, I think.

Comment: Yes absolutely right, can one manage to place components in one slide in a suble way : dimensions margins, ?

Comment: Another list of alternatives to `beamer`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15198/are-there-alternatives-to-beamer-for-slides

Answer (score 0):

I tried `Koma-script` and found it quite flexible.

```
\documentclass[landscape,paper=128mm:96mm,fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl}
\pagestyle{empty}\linespread{1.12}
```

If you want the `frame` environment, try this:

```
\newenvironment{frame}{\clearpage\begin{center}\vspace*{\fill}}{\vspace*{\fill}\end{center}\clearpage}
```

More detailed information is in this article from PracTeX Journal: [Scientific Presentations with LaTeX](http://tug.org/pracjourn/2010-2/hofert/scientific_presentations_practex.pdf)

Comment: Well, this gives you flexibility in the sense that you can do everything in a familiar way if you have not learn `beamer` yet.

Comment: KOMA-Script isn't really designed for presentations, though, is it? It lacks most of the functionality people would expect from a replacement for `beamer`.

Comment: Thanks J.Xu ! schtandard it is designed for presentations !

Comment: @schtandard At least for me, functionality and flexibility are not always the same thing. I was struggling getting a minimalist look in `beamer` for my slides, until I tried `koma-script`.